# Splunk Alert with run a script action

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

Is there any way to run external script with source IP (source IP of device which sent alert to splunk, host= value in event) address as variable?
There is in splunk documentation few variables but non of them are host.
I need to trigger config download from Solar Winds upon change of config. All syslog messages are sent to splunk. So when alert is triggered it would run script ./update $SOURCE_HOST

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an [Alert](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Alert) on anything you like. If you want the Alert to run a script, just parse-out the information you need into a field so you can pass it to your script.